# Dynamic Rmarkdown pdf layout

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I need to create a *dynamic* template in r markdown.  The template should consist of 6 cells like

```
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       1       -       2       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       3       -       4       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       5       -       6       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
```

Ideally each cell should contain a different graph or some text. However, some cells need to be combined if the output is too big. For example

```
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       1       -       2       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       3       -       4       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
-                               -
-                               -
-                5              -
-                               -
---------------------------------
```

or

```
---------------------------------
-               -               -
-               -               -
-       1       -       2       -
-               -               -
---------------------------------
-                               -
-                               -
-                               -
-                               -
-                               -
-                               -
-                5              -
-                               -
---------------------------------
```

I found on how to do it in [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73954/how-to-split-a-page-in-six-equally-sized-sectors) but I don't know how to implement in using r markdown and how to make it dynamic.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Is this for graphics or textual content?

Comment: @r2evans Unfortunately both.  I guess what I am really asking is how to create a template where the output from my r code can go.

Comment: Plots-only would be a much easier hack: use `layout` (base graphics) or `gridExtra` (`lattice`, `ggplot2`) to control things dynamically. To treat this like a flexible n-up page is well beyond what I can do ... and I suspect beyond what R-markdown is able to support. LaTeX *might* be able to do it, though I suspect your best chance is to ask over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please have a look at [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/), which might be what you need.

Comment: @r2evans That's actually a brilliant hack. I can use `geom_text` or `geom_annotate` to add text to a blank plot to create the illusion of text vignettes.  I'll give the idea a shot using the 'cowplot' plot package and report back how it went

Comment: @TCZhang flexdashboard is one of the option i am exploring but it might not be flexible enough. I also need to add lines between the different sections and find a way to make into pdf documents.  I am very surprised that there is no standard way of doing that given the ubiquitousness of this type of reporting.